# Mac OS Pygame using a deprecated function CGSFlushWindow

Tags: python, pygame

I am running Python 2.7.3 in 32 bit mode underOS Mountain Lion and I have just started using Pygame. I keep getting the following error message in the terminal window:

```
2012-12-31 10:58:03.695 Python[12097:f07] Warning once: This application, or a library it
uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of 
QuickDraw and move to Quartz.

Dec 31 10:58:03 bigden.local Python[12097] <Error>: The function `CGSFlushWindow' is 
obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a 
library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an 
overall degradation of system performance. Please use `CGSFlushWindowContentRegion' 
instead.
```

Any way to avoid this?  Is there a Pygame fix coming?

Comment: What version of pygame are you using?  `pygame.version.ver`.  I'm using 1.9.2pre and I no longer get that error.

Comment: @jgritty I am using 1.9.1.

Comment: I'd recommend installing the version for lion, http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing version [1.9.2pre](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip).  I don't get those errors any more.