# when i write "import pygame" in pycharm it says: no module named pygame (mac os)

Tags: python, macos, pygame

At first  the version of pygame i downloaded was: `pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3`

then i got the error message when i run the program :

```
The function `CGSFlushWindow' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update.
```

so i adopt the suggestion from [Mac OS Pygame using a deprecated function CGSFlushWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103699/mac-os-pygame-using-a-deprecated-function-cgsflushwindow),

then i downloaded the new version which is [here](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip).

but now, a new following  error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Crayon_277/Develop/Project/Pygame/my_pygame/my_pygame.py", line 3, in     <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

i notice that the pygame package is in this directory (A) : `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
not this (B) : `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

so i try to copy it from A to B, but it doesn't work.

someone reminds me that i should see if `sys.path` contains pygame.
and the answer is YES when i check it out.

so what i should do now? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your python interpreter can't find the pygame package. This is because you don't have the pygame package in the site-packages of the interpreter you are using.

You can probably fix that with an egg-link file in the site-packages of the python interpreter you are actually using. An egg-link file is a plain text file with a path inside, pointing to the place the real egg should be.

It could be something like this:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame
```

And just store it as `pygame.egg-link`, within your interpreter site-packages, i.e.: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

You can also do this with a `.pth` file. A `.pth` file is "kind of" the same, with directory paths that should be searched for packages as well. Create one, (give it a descriptive name), store it in the site-packages and you are good to go.

**STEP BY STEP**

- Create a plain text file
- Write the following line inside `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/XXXX` being XXXX the folder where the `pygame` package is.
- Save the `.pth` it in your python interpreter site-packages with the name `externals`for instance. This means the full path must be: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/externals.pth`
- Run your python interpreter and `import pygame`

Comment: Sorry ,i'm a cookie. i've no idea what u're talking about.So ,where is the egg-link file? Am i going to make this a new file or..?

Comment: I added a TODO list in my answer, check it out.

Comment: how can i save it as .pth file?  i switch to plaintext and i did rename the file externals.pth as finder show to me. but it's been externals.pth.txt when i check it in pycharm . As result ,it also says import error ether in pycharm or IDLE

Comment: You can't really expect that we solve all your problems. If you can't change a file's extension, google it.